# Linux Mint livecd does not recognize Windows 8 partition

Tags: linux, windows-8, multi-boot, linux-mint, grub2

My system has two SSDs. I re-installed Windows 8 onto the disk0. I want to install Linux mint on the other SSD.

Secure-boot is disabled, fastboot is disabled, csm is enabled

I run Linux Mint 16 x64 Cinnamon liveusb and run the installer. When I get to the manual partition installation page, I only see /dev/sda. It doesn't show the Windows partition. [In fact, I have exactly this user's problem (see the imgur links)](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1kw9pz/). But this use doesn't say what he did to solve it other than he removed GPT. But I thought Windows 8 requires GPT?

I run `sudo fdisk -l` and I see this error at the top:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

It detects /dev/sda as NTFS, and it detects /dev/sdb as unallocated space (which is the second SSD).

Then I run `sudo blkid` and I see that:

/dev/sda1 LABEL="...." UUID=... TYPE="ntfs"

/dev/sda2 ..................... TYPE="ntfs"

But that's weird... Windows is installed on sda1 (labeled disk0 in Window's installer). So where is the option to install Mint on the other SSD (labeled disk1 in Window's installer)? It doesn't even see windows as already having been installed on sda1.

So I try reinstalling Windows again, except I install it on disk1. I install Linux Mint on sda1 (the installer still doesn't see the Windows partitions though), and it installs fine. Then I reboot, but it boots directly into Windows as though it were the only OS installed.

Also, I have tried EasyBCD and it does not detect Linux Mint at all. In any case, I would like to use grub2 and not some Windows solution.

How do I install Linux Mint alongside Windows 8 on separate SSDs?? Could I have a step-by-step on what to do from Installing a fresh copy of Windows 8 to Installing Linux mint? This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I still find it worthwhile answering, because I just had a similar issue myself. The best way to answer your question "How do I install Linux Mint alongside Windows 8 on separate SSDs?" is by pointing to the link that answered the question for me:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2014/06/11/how-to-dual-boot-linux-mint-17-and-windows-8-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/

Remark, the above mentioned guide discusses dual boot on one hard drive, but it works equally well for two hard drives (I have one SSD with Win 8 and another with Linux).

Comment: That looks like a good tutorial.  However, the purpose of Super User is to build a knowledge base for long term reference.  If the link disappears or is unavailable, your answer would have no value.  For these types of answers, we ask that you include the essential information in the answer (a synopsis or copy and paste), and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.